# SCVMM 2022 Windows Server 2022 Bare Metal Provisioning Error

Tags: scvmm, windows-server-2022

We recently updated our SCVMM manager from 2016 to 2022. Now we want to add new hypervisors by using the physical host provisioning option from the SCVMM.

We have a physical hardware profile with a windows server 2022 vhd which was installed from a 2022 ISO and then syspreped (OOBE + generalized). However the setup of the hypervisor always fails at step 1.2.8 in the SCVMM (Retrieve information about the OS being deployed). The following error is displayed in the job:

"Error (21117)
The operating system in the specified virtual hard disk does not support native VHD boot.

Recommended Action
Verify that the operating system in the selected virtual hard disk is Windows Server 2008 R2 or later."

In the console of the server we can see the following error:

"Error 8099527d"

The log is showing "CarmineException::CarmineException: CarmineError: 21117, hr: 0x8099527d"

In the event log of the hosting vmm server there are also related informational entries to this (doesn't show up on every failed attempt):

"Virtual Machine Manager will not deploy an OS to computer with SMBIOS GUID: MAC: because the GUID does not match any that have pending operating system deployments in VMM. The PXE request is being passed on to the next WDS PXE provider.

We also tried using Windows server 2019 which ends with the exact same problem.

Our old windows server 2016 image is still working. The issue seems to be because of the image/vhd we're using. Are there any known problems with this? Are we using the wrong method of provisioning the image? I've seen a video with someone using server 2019 so at least that should be possible to use.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone with a similar issue finds this: I was able to solve the issue by building a reference image following this (old) blogpost: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/adiyq/end-to-end-bare-metal-provisioning-with-scvmm-2012-sp1-r2-part-6-building-a-reference-image-with-mdt-2013 Just note you will also need to install the ADK Win PE Addon to create the image or you will run into an error when Updating the Deployment Share.

Installation of the HyperV continued afterwards and other issues with drivers were easily solveable.